# In Jupyter, how do you tell which browser you are in?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, altair

In my Jupyter notebook, I need to know whether I am running in Chrome or Firefox because the code to save a figure in Altair is different depending on the browser (https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/saving_charts.html).

How can I do this?

Comment: From the docs, it looks like you need to have Selenium and either ChromeDriver or GeckoDriver installed as dependencies. These packages set up a "headless" browser to render and save the images, separately from the browser you are using to run the Jupyter notebook. Altair defaults to ChromeDriver, so probably just install that one unless you have a special need for GeckoDriver render.

Comment: I have both installed and working, but I run the notebook in both browsers and I need to know whether I need `webdriver='firefox'` when calling `chart.save()`.

Comment: I do not think you need that. If I understand correctly, the `chart.save()` command will start a new headless browser on the notebook server process, separate from your browser that is running the Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 3):

The Jupyter kernel (i.e. Python backend) has no direct information about the frontend that is connected to it. But you can use system tools to try to infer what browser processes are running. For example, the [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module allows you to list running processes. I have a Chrome and Safari browsers open currently, and I get these results:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> 'Google Chrome' in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())            
True
>>> 'Firefox' in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())                  
False
>>> 'Safari' in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())                   
True
```

Some caveats:

- the process name might vary from operating system to operating system: I would check on that if it's important to work consistently across platforms.
- this does not tell you whether the user is using this particular frontend for viewing the Jupyter notebook, but whether the process of that name is running at all.
- For saving altair charts, note that the browser alone is not enough: you'll also need the user to have chromedriver installed for Chrome, or geckodriver installed for Firefox. It may be better to detect whether those drivers are installed rather than detecting the currently running browser. See [Saving Charts](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/saving_charts.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If the Jupyter kernel doesn't know, what do you think of something like `%%javascript
var command = "user_agent = " + "'" + navigator.userAgent + "'";
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(command);` ? Then I can try to parse the `user_agent` variable in a Python cell.